# Can I use autowired EntityManager across different services with DB locking?

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 5 project I have 2 services and I autowire `EntityManager` into both of them:

```
class MyService1 {

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
class MyService2 {

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, MyService1 $myService1)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->myService1 = $myService1;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I run some DB transaction inside one of the `MyService2` functions:

```
$this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
```

and I call some helper function from `MyService1` which uses also its own `$entityManager` property and should be executed also inside that same DB transaction.

My question is: am I **guaranteed** that both Services will be autowired with the same (one and only) instance of `$entityManager`? This is important because I need them both to work inside the same DB locking scope.

I did test it experimentally with `dump()` function and they do seem to point to the very same instance. However I did not find in docs whether this is a sure behavior, or result of some random caching which is not guaranteed to happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can expect it to be the same instance. The autowired instance is identical across the entire application. And a transaction started with the Entity Manager instance will be the same across different services, as long as you use the default connection.

This is basically the idea behind [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). There is only one instance, and it is being shared across downstream services.

Looking at Design Patterns historically, this is the extension of the “Singleton” paradigm, where you would have a global class with a static instantiator. With Dependency Injection, the instance is managed by the DI container, but it is always the same (identical) object.

By the way, a lock is something different than a transaction. The transaction is only valid in the scope of your current connection, while a lock affects all connections until it is released.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I mixed up locking and transaction terminology in the question because what I do actually uses both

Comment: Yeah, happens to me as well :D Just wanted to make sure there’s no confusion about what the entity manager and DBAL can do for you.

Comment: I would quibble with your assertion that dependency injection requires shared services.  It does not.  However, by default, the Symfony container does define [services as shared](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html) which means the same instance is always injected.  But you can define non-shared services which means that a new instance is created each time injection is used.  It's a minor quibble but I think it is an important concept.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks for the clarification, I wasn’t really aware of that, but it does make sense. I’ll amend the post later today accordingly.